# Postgresql 12.2 taking lot of resident memory over period of time

Tags: database, postgresql, centos, psql

Postgresql 12.2 is taking lot of resident memory over a period of time.

```
pidstat -l -r -p ALL  | grep -i [p]ostgres |  gawk '{ sum += $7 }; END { print sum }'
```

command gives me 2GB after a period of 5days, initiallly it is 350 MB. Is there anyway to reduce it or not allow it to occupy much memory.

Answer (score 0):

RSS includes all the shared memory each process has ever accessed, independently.  So summing it up is counting the same memory over and over again.  Since the summation you are reporting is meaningless, there is no point in trying to reduce it.  If you think you have a memory problem, looking at the maximum RSS across any of the processes is probably a better way to diagnose it. But if there is no reason to think there is a memory problem, don't try to invent one.

Comment: Owkay i get that, but i want to reduce, is there anyway. Also, there are a lot of processes which are idle when i do `ps aux | grep postgres` . What could be the reason? 

Apart from that is there anyway to limit or expel the redundant process accumulating over time.

Comment: Look in the view pg_stat_activity to see where the idle connections are coming from and what they were doing just before they went idle.  Maybe your app is failing to close connections when it is done with them.